# Java, send e-mail: verify whether valid host is provided in e-mail address

Tags: java, email, verification

Our website sends e-mails to the e-mail address which a user enters on our website. Some people enter garbage e-mail addresses. How can we find out, whether at least the host of the entered address is a valid one? Simply trying to open a socket at port 25 of the entered host?

Update: I've found a [Java library for DNS stuff](http://www.dnsjava.org/). What record should I check?

Comment: I asked a similar question regarding this for php. The best bet would be to do a DNS check on the hostname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look up the MX record for the host-part from DNS...but there are many corner-cases. Don't reinvent the wheel (you're bound to get it wrong), try to find an existing library. I only know the one from Snertsoft for C (integrated into the commercial [milter-sender](http://www.snertsoft.com/sendmail/milter-sender/)), though.

[Disclaimer: I'm a happy user of milter-sender]

[**Edit**]
Take a look at [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-5) Sec.5, which describes the rules for looking up the right host.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are verifying (using a regular expression) that a valid e-mail address was entered. Otherwise, there is no point in checking whether the host is valid.

Comment: Thats a nice bag of worms right there...  http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Why not just make the email address optional, if users don't want to provide one then they don't have to, if they do want to provide one make them enter it twice and validate both values match.

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I want. I want to prevent something like `sdjkfsjf@fjdskjfsd.com`.